# DataOutputStream.write() not visibly working, but DataOutputStream.writeUTF() is

Tags: java, ssl, server, client

I have a client/server pair in which I have this messaging application to which i'm trying to add SSL support. The client/server normally use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to send/receive their info, working with byte arrays (DataOutputStream.write(byte[]) and DataInputStream.readFully(byte[])). But for some reason, that doesn't work with SSL sockets. I've tried using DataOutputStream.writeUTF() and DataInputStream.readUTF() and it works. I even tried using other types of reader/writers like BufferedReader/BufferedWriter, and they work, but when I try to use bytes, it doesn't send anything. What's weirder is the fact that after checking the DataOutputStream.size() in both sides, they both print that they have sended data.

Server side:

```
logger.info("Waiting to accept a new client socket");
clientSocket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();

logger.info("Socket accepted successfully");
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=newDataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

logger.trace("Socket is going to read");

int data=dataInputStream.available();
byte[] message=new byte[data];

dataInputStream.readFully(message);
logger.trace("Message received: {}",message);

logger.trace("Gonna respond");
if(message.length>0){
    dataOutputStream.write(message,0,message.length);
}else{
    String response=new String("wot?".getBytes(),"ASCII");
    dataOutputStream.write(response.getBytes(),0,response.getBytes().length);
}
dataOutputStream.flush();

logger.trace("Chars written: {}",dataOutputStream.size());
```

Client side:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
logger.trace("SSL Socket factory created");
javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket sslSocket = (javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(url, port);
logger.trace("SSL Socket created");
sslSocket.setSoTimeout(6000);

outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();
inputStream=sslSocket.getInputStream();

DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(inputStream);
logger.trace("Input and output created");

//dataOutputStream.writeBytes(frame);
//dataOutputStream.writeUTF(frame);

dataOutputStream.write(frame.getBytes(),0,frame.getBytes().length);

dataOutputStream.flush();
logger.trace("Frame {} sent",frame);
logger.trace("Bytes sent: {}",dataOutputStream.size());

int data=dataInputStream.available();
byte[] messageRead = new byte[data];
dataInputStream.readFully(messageRead);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I've been looking around and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Misuse of `available()`, and invalid assumption that TCP supports messages. I suggest you use `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` for everything, *instead of* all this code, or read and write lines with `BufferedReader.`

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response! Secondly, TCP must be supporting the messages (we are using the ISO8583 protocol, by the way), since we already have some functioning messages with test responses. The problem comes when we try to implement SSL to already existing ones. And we can't use `readUTF()` and `writeUTF` because apparently it didn't work properly as needed

Comment: To elaborate on EJP's point, the [contract of InputStream.available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) specifically states “It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.”  In retrospect, the method should have been named `availableWithoutBlocking()`.